# Get the number of different elements of a column when grouping by another column

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with this pandas dataframe:

```
      Id     nb   sampleId
0      A     1       sA
1      B     2       sB
2      C     3       sD
3      D     4       sF
4      D     5       sF
5      A     6       sF
6      E     7       sF
7      F     8       sO
8      G     9       SP
9      H    10       SS
10     I    11       sK
11     C    12       sL
```

I am trying to get another dataframe grouping by `Id` as first column, and getting the number of different `sampleId` as second column. So my desired output would be this:

```
     Id  sampleId
0     A         2
1     B         1
2     C         2
3     D         1
4     E         1
5     F         1
6     G         1
7     H         1
8     I         1
```

I have tryed this:

```
df2=df.groupby(['Id'])['sampleId'].count().reset_index()
```

which is just counting the number of times each `Id` is repeated, not what I am looking for (as you can see, it seems that element D is repeated in two different sampleIds, when actually it is occurring twice in the same sampleId):

```
  srcId  sampleId
0     A         2
1     B         1
2     C         2
3     D         2
4     E         1
5     F         1
6     G         1
7     H         1
8     I         1
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use -

```
df.groupby(['Id'])['sampleId'].nunique().reset_index()
```

**Output**

```
Id  sampleId
0   A   2
1   B   1
2   C   2
3   D   1
4   E   1
5   F   1
6   G   1
7   H   1
8   I   1
```